# last 4 month/week data

Tags: splunk, splunk-formula

How can we get timechart for last 4 month i have tried the below query but its giving me fixed last 4 month data like only for MAR,APR,MAY,JUN .. how can i get for AUG SEP OCT and NOV ..

PFB tried query..

```
index=foo earliest=-1mon@mon latest=-0mon@mon Technology="Sourcefire" 
| timechart span=1day count AS JUN-2020 
| appendcols [search index=SI earliest=-2mon@mon latest=-1mon@mon Technology="Sourcefire" 
  | timechart span=1day count AS MAY-2020] 
| appendcols [search index=SI earliest=-3mon@mon latest=-2mon@mon Technology="Sourcefire" 
  | timechart span=1day count AS APR-2020] 
| appendcols [search index=SI earliest=-4mon@mon latest=-3mon@mon Technology="Sourcefire" 
  | timechart span=1day count AS MAR-2020] 
| table _time JUN-2020 MAY-2020 APR-2020 MAR-2020
```

also can you please help to get last 4 week data ..
i tried below which is not working..

```
index=Foo earliest=-1w@w1 latest=-0w@w1 
| timechart span=1hour count by  RuleAction  
| appendcols [search index=FOO_1 | timechart span=1hour count by blocked ]
  appendcols [search index=Foo earliest=-2w@w1 latest=-1w@w1 
| timechart span=1hour count by  RuleAction 
| appendcols [search index=FOO_1  
| timechart span=1hour count by blocked ]
 appendcols [search index=Foo earliest=-3w@w1 latest=-2w@w1 
  | timechart span=1hour count by  RuleAction 
  | appendcols [search index=FOO_1  
  | timechart span=1hour count by blocked ]
 appendcols [search index=FOO earliest=-4w@w1 latest=-3w@w1 
| timechart span=1hour count by  RuleAction 
| appendcols [search index=ngss*_sourcefire_seceventFOO_1 
  | timechart span=1hour count by blocked ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `timechart` over the previous 4 months then why not use this?

```
index=foo earliest=-1mon@mon latest=-0mon@mon Technology="Sourcefire"
| append [ search index=SI earliest=-4mon@mon latest=-1mon@mon Technology="Sourcefire" ]
| timechart span=1d count
```

The problem with the second query is a common one.  The `appendcols` command is order-dependent.  That means events from the subsearch are matched with events from the main search on a one-for-one basis.  If the order in which events are returned varies among the subsearches then the results will be unpredictable.  Use `append` instead and let the `timechart` command sort it out.

Comment: Nope its not working as expected .. just showing date only for last one month for rest its just showing the count ..

Comment: index=foo earliest=-1mon@mon latest=-0mon@mon Technology="Sourcefire"
| append [ search index=SI earliest=-4mon@mon latest=-1mon@mon Technology="Sourcefire" ]
| timechart span=1d count